# how to do update using ajax jquery in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i am developing plugin where i have to update the single record onchanging the select option element , i tried using wordpres codex way ,but i am struck can please anyone help me out here, below is my code

```js
function ajaxFunction(str,id) {

    var payment_selected = str;
    var id=id;
    var queryString = '&id_took='+id+'&sel='+payment_selected;        
    var data = {
        'action' : 'my_action',
        'payment_selected': payment_selected,
        'id'    : id            
    };

    jQuery.post(admin_url("admin-ajax.php"), data, function(response) {
    jQuery("#status").html(response);
    });
}
```

```html
/* this is a php file , i used in the plugin where below html form appears  */
<?php

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {    
     global $wpdb;
     $id_selected = $_POST['payment_selected']; 
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $table_name_payment = $wpdb->prefix . "online_booking_system_model";    
     $result_pay =  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name_payment SET payment_status = $id_selected WHERE id=$id"));
     echo "success";

?>
/* this is  the html file */
 foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>  
 <table>
  <td><?php echo $row->payment_status; ?></td>
<select  name='payment_select' id="payment_select" onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value,<?php echo $row->id ?>)">   
                            <option value="Payment Due">Payment Due</option>
                        <option value="Payment completed">Payment Completed</option>
                        </select> 
                         <?php } ?>
                         <table>
                         <div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: `$result_pay =  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name_payment SET payment_status = $id_selected WHERE id=$id"));` If you prepare a statement, you must `->execute()` it, not `->query()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i tried in my own way its working fine for me, below is my answer

```js
function ajaxFunction(str,id) {

    var payment_selected = str;
 var id=id;
 var queryString = '&id_took='+id+'&sel='+payment_selected;
          var data = {
         'action' : 'my_action',
        'payment_selected': payment_selected,
        'id'    : id            
              };
     jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
          jQuery("#status").html(response);
      });

 
    }
```

```html
/* write this php function outside of all the function*/
     <?php 

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    
     global $wpdb;
     $id_selected = $_POST['payment_selected'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    $table_name_payment = $wpdb->prefix . "online_booking_system_model";   
  
//   $result_pay =  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name_payment SET payment_status = $id_selected WHERE id = $id"));
     $result_pay =  $wpdb->update(
            $table_name_payment, //table
            array( 'payment_status' => $id_selected), //data
               array('id' => $id) //data format   
        );  

}
    
    ?>
    foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>  
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
              <td>                       
                        <select  name='payment_select' id="payment_select" onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value,<?php echo $row->id ?>)">   
                            <option value="Payment Due">Payment Due</option>
                        <option value="Payment completed">Payment Completed</option>
                        </select>                       
                    </td>
                    <div id="status"></div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ajaxFunction(str,id) {
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'action' : 'my_action',
                    'payment_selected': payment_selected,
                    'id'    : id  
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response=='success'){ 
                    jQuery("#status").html(response);
                    }
                }
});
}
```

PHP Code,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {    
 global $wpdb;
 $id_selected = $_POST['payment_selected']; 
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $table_name_payment = $wpdb->prefix . "online_booking_system_model";    
 $result_pay =  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name_payment SET payment_status = $id_selected WHERE id=$id"));
 echo "success";
}
?>
```

HTML code,

```
 <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>  
 <table>
 <tr><td><?php echo $row->payment_status; ?></td>
 <select  name='payment_select' id="payment_select" onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value,<?php echo $row->id ?>)">   
        <option value="Payment Due">Payment Due</option>
        <option value="Payment completed">Payment Completed</option>
 </select> 
 <?php } ?>
 </td></tr>
 <table>
 <div id="status"></div>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: try to echo your query and check in phpmyadmin.

Comment: this is my fiddle you can paste your code over here. [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sunildora_94/ycpg0m2r/)

Comment: plz, now check.